# Ajax load contents and append related urls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to use Ajax in a Project.

The Idea is when i click a Tab,
The Relevant Data should load according to that Tab.

But it also should append the Url on address bar of current form that i am in.

Let Suppose i clicked the ERP Tab, so then ERP Divs should load inside the page but also the relative url should also show
e-g
www.mydomain.com\erp

i know about .load function, but with it it dont update the url on address bar.
plus data will be coming from different files.

Also Left Side Menus will be coming from Database on Role Base.

i am using codeigniter in this project

i want to have Url functionality as it will be easy for user to access that page directly with the complete url plus it also gives bookmark advantage too..

Here is the screenshot for more convenience.
[image]

Comment: You can serve a regular "blank" page, and on dom ready you fire the ajax request and populate the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't change the actual URL without a page reload.

You'll have to use 'jquery-address' library. Check out https://github.com/asual/jquery-address

Comment: This actually isn't true. history.pushState() allows you to change the URL without a page reload.

Comment: Thankyou for reply, cuz of your reply i thought to find of libraries.
and jquery address library is good, but i find jquery bbq library more convenient.
Anyhow Thanks for sharing the jquery-address link.

Answer (score 0):

I would do two different things here:

1. To change the URL dynamically without page load, use the new [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) method. If you are supporting older browsers, [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) is essentially the same API that falls back to a hashtag method. Note that these URLs are **not accessible from the outside.** Thus:
2. When a user travels to one of those URLs, default the open tab to whichever one you are trying to. You will have to capture the intended route and work some javascript magic on it.